# How to make my screen wait till my child window get closed, in firefox

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox

Issue: Should restrict the webpage from submission and moving to the next, till the child window gets closed.

Technology: jsp

Browser: firefox.

Code used for Opening:

`retValue = window.open(child_url,',',"Height=400px,Width=670px,status:no,top=190px,left=200px");`

Desc:

Clicked on one link in the page and opened up the child window from the firefox browser using the window.open command. But just after the click of the link, along with the opening up of the child window, the main page is also getting submitted and moved to the next page.

The same logic in ie works fine. In ie am using showModalDialog() which works without any issue.

NB: Hoping for an alternative way, which is something other than giving if conditions to the page submission line.

Could someone pls help... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you move up to the [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  It's browser-independent, and your user will understand that he is interacting with a modal dialog that must be closed before proceeding.  With a separate window or tab (your current solution), it's too easy for the user to get lost and click away from the browser altogether.